# Can the Nvidia 330m support 2 outputs @ the same time?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, acer-aspire

I have a new Acer aspire 5745G which has the Nvidia 330m on it

I want to connect 2 x 24" displays on it
 - one via VGA
 - second via HDMI

is it possible to get that to work or is it limited to only 1 Output @ the time?

Answer (score 1):

It's limited to one output plus your built in display or two outputs with no built in display. I have tested this with the 335m I can't imagine the lower model hardware would allow three monitors... especially because the the 335m is basically just an oc'd 330 with more video memory.